# Sort full name in alphabetical order in R

Tags: r, sorting, tidyr

Full names (and titles, etc.) generally need to be separated into multiple columns to sort rows alphabetically by "last name." I've never come across a simple way to achieve this in SQL when a single column contains the full name.

However, I know R has thousands of libraries - and although I haven't come across any examples that can do this *without* separating the first name, last name and titles into their own respective columns - I thought I'd see if there's a slightly more efficient way to deal with this situation.

The data set I'm working with has a single column with **full names**.  For example:

```
     Names
1    Robert Johnson                                  
2    Billy Joel                               
3    Donald Fagen                          
4    Trent Reznor                                
5    Wolfgang Mozart
```

I need to sort these alphabetically without creating additional columns.  So far, I'm not sure this is possible, but I did find a relatively painless work-around.  Thankfully, each name follows a "first name"(space)"last name" convention.  So I can use separate() from the *tidyr* library to easily isolate last names:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

# Separate into "first name" and "last name" columns
data %<>% separate(Names, c('first_name', 'last_name'), sep = ' ')

    first_name       last_name
1     Robert           Johnson                                    
2     Billy            Joel                                    
3     Donald           Fagen                                    
4     Trent            Reznor
5     Wolfgang         Mozart
```

Then I can sort the new "last name" column alphabetically with arrange() and immediately rebuild the original column with unite():

```
# Arrange rows alphabetically by last name
data %<>% arrange(last_name)

# Rebuild original column and dissolve temporary 2nd column
data %>% unite(Names, first_name:last_name, sep=' ')
```

This successfully rebuilds the original table and alphabetizes column "Names" via last names.  Is there another way to achieve this **without** 
ever (even temporarily) creating that second "last name" column?  Any additional R libraries would be accepted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tidyverse` function to use here would be `str_extract` from the `stringr` package.  This is also a bit simpler than `gsub` or `str_replace`, since you don't have to replace the captured part of the string with `""`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

data %>%
    arrange(str_extract(Names,'\\s.*$'))
```

Comment: Yes, works great and reduces code from 3 lines to 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `dplyr` and a simple `gsub` call.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  arrange(gsub(".*\\s", "", Names))

            Names
1    Donald Fagen
2      Billy Joel
3  Robert Johnson
4 Wolfgang Mozart
5    Trent Reznor
```

Comment: Good solution. Worked on my end. Thank you!